# How to remove "Time Zone" element "user_register_form" form using hook_form_alter

Tags: 8, forms

I analyzed the "Create new account" page of drupal by using hook_form_alter and $form variable. as you see, #form_id value is: "user_register_form" and other elements are as following:

```
attributes->Array
administer_users->Array
#attached->Array
#cache->Array
account->Array
language->Array
#entity_builders->Array
#process->Array
#parents->Array
user_picture->Array
actions->Array
#form_id->user_register_form
#type->form
#action->form_action_p_pvdeGsVG5zNF_XLGPTvYSKCf43t8qZYSwcfZl2uzM
#build_id->form-78GnGyO2iwZsooojZLCOiAw9pYXyDqngJ5C0DU_EzUQ
form_build_id->Array
form_id->Array
#id->user-register-form
#method->post
#theme_wrappers->Array
#defaults_loaded->1
#tree->
#validate->Array
#submit->Array
#theme->Array
contact->Array
```

I want to remove "Time Zone" element of this form (user_register_form), which of this array elements should I unset to remove that element?

Comment: Drupal 8 provided admin path at: admin/config/regional/settings
where we can un-check the option "Users may set their own time zone." It's working in drupal 8

Comment: Honestly, there is no reason not to use the admin here than to add code you do not need.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED

As @KrishaWeb and @Kevin said:
Drupal 8 provided admin path at: admin/config/regional/settings to do it.

Comment: I did not know it was possible to use admin for this.
Using admin is better.